# Serializing custom classes with pyyaml

Tags: python, pyyaml

I would like to serialize a custom class (which I cannot modify or monkey patch) by specifying how such class instances should be serialized.

Here's the setup:

```py
# some custom class which I cannot modify
class Custom:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

# data I want to serialize
data = [Custom(1, 2), Custom(101, 102)]
```

Here's how I would do it for JSON:

```py
import json

# helper function to handle the custom class
def default(d):
    if isinstance(d, Custom):
        return dict(a=d.a, b=d.b)

print(json.dumps(data, default=default))
# expected and actual output: [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 101, "b": 102}]
```

I'm struggling to find an equivalent solution for `pyyaml`:

```py
import yaml

def yaml_equivalent_of_default():
    "YOUR SOLUTION GOES HERE"

print(yaml.dump(data))
# expected output:
# - a: 1
#   b: 2
# - a: 101
#   b: 102
```

I've tried different approaches mentioned in the [pyyaml docs](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this should work if the custom class members/fields can be pickled:

```py
import yaml

class Custom:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

data_to_serialize = [Custom(1, 2), Custom(101, 102)]

def yaml_equivalent_of_default(dumper, data):
    dict_representation = data.__dict__
    node = dumper.represent_dict(dict_representation)
    return node

yaml.add_representer(Custom, yaml_equivalent_of_default)

print(yaml.dump(data_to_serialize))
```

Output:

```sh
- a: 1
  b: 2
- a: 101
  b: 102
```

The signature of the `representer` is `def add_representer(data_type, representer, Dumper=Dumper)`, so it's possible to pass a `Damper` to it. All the available dumpers are `['BaseDumper', 'SafeDumper', 'Dumper']`.

Comment: How could I miss the `Dumper` part? Thanks @QuirkyBit!