# How to handle Path objects when dumping to YAML

Tags: python, yaml

I have an object that contains PoxisPath() as data members. How do I write this out as a YAML file? I currently do:

```
safe_dump_all(data, f_out, indent=2, default_flow_style=False)
```

but I'm getting an error that it doesn't know how to reprsent Path objects.

```
Type: <class 'yaml.representer.RepresenterError'>
2024-02-29 15:28:18 ERROR    - Value: ('cannot represent an object', PosixPath('/a/b/c')
```

When using JSON, I solved it by writing a custom Encoder like this:

```
  class MyJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
        def default(self, o):
            if isinstance(o, Path):
                return os.fspath(o)
            return JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

but not sure how to do it for YAML.

Comment: Same way, but it's a "representer" not an encoder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62232688/serializing-custom-classes-with-pyyaml, https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#constructors-representers-resolvers

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link above, this works:

```
from pathlib import Path
from os import fspath

def yaml_equivalent_of_path(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_str(str(data))

yaml.add_multi_representer(Path, yaml_equivalent_of_path)
```